# how to generate mirrored sequence of numbers

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sequence, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm looking for a way (lightweight one-cell formula solution) how to generate a mirrored sequencing based on the count of unique values. example for 2, 3 and 4 given values:

[image]

- input values are always unique (if that matters)
- output sequence needs to be spread across the range of cells (as shown on image)

Comment: You'll need one more item in addition to the count.  That is, a way to tell where your cell is in the sequence.  If you have an index row, thats pretty easy- if index is less than or equal to the count, value is the index.  Otherwise value is (2*count+1-index).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following

```
={TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(ROW(A15)-ROW(A12)+1)), 
  TRANSPOSE(SORT(SEQUENCE(ROW(A15)-ROW(A12)+1),1,0))}
```

[image]

---

*Later addition*
*As [commented by player0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63199924/how-to-generate-mirrored-sequence-of-numbers/63200206?noredirect=1#comment111758285_63200206), one can also use*

```
={TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(COUNTUNIQUE(A12:A15)+1)), 
      TRANSPOSE(SORT(SEQUENCE(COUNTUNIQUE(A12:A15)+1),1,0))}
```

*The difference being that using the first formula one can create the sequence even when referencing just empty cells.*

Comment: I was hoping for something shorter, but yeah, this may work too. (ended up using https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqrwE.png). thx.

Comment: *"...ended up using..."*. That is nice as well. Do you mind if I added to my answer? Users rarely make it to the comments.

Comment: sure np, go for it

Answer (score 1):

I set myself the challenge of doing this in a single function - it must be possible, right? You just need a symmetrical function.

After some thought I came up with a function of the form:

```
y=c-abs(x)
```

So if you can generate x-values like (for the case of n=3)

```
-2.5 -1.5 -.5 0.5 1.5 2.5
```

you just need to subtract their absolute values from 3.5 to get

```
1 2 3 3 2 1
```

Unfortunately Sequence will only generate integer values so the formula isn't as tidy as one would wish:

```
=ArrayFormula(counta(A:A)+0.5-abs(sequence(1,counta(A:A)*2,-counta(A:A))+0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: nice idea. I played a bit with it and accidentally realized mirror sequence can be even mirrored like https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVrjP.png thx